# i want remove duplicate values from the excel sheet in java

Tags: java, excel

I have an excel sheet where I have duplicate values for many rows. How can I make it have unique values? I'm looking for some code which will remove duplicates from this excel sheet and store it back in the same file.

Comment: I am a bit confused as to what you want to do. Could you give an example of what a small excel sheet starts out as and what you want it to end as?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to play around with Excel Spreadsheets you need a Java library like [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/) or [docx4j](http://dev.plutext.org/trac/docx4j). I'm afraid I do not have any code samples for you but look at the project web sites.

You could also look into converting the spreadsheet to CSV format and then parse that to remove duplicates etc.